# Opencart Footer Not Showing When logged

Tags: php, opencart, footer

I need help with Opencart.  When the customer is logged in the footer won't show up but if the customer is not logged in, the footer shows correctly.  Please help me:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HZT6.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/urVBS.png

Thank you for help.

Comment: is it possible that there is code that is failing that is only included when the user is logged?  Or if you have an `exit()` or `die()` somewhere only when logged?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not logged status but rather, SSL or not.  For whatever reason, the footer is not rendered with `https` protocol, but shows up fine with `http`.  It could be a problem with your theme, or it's possible that your webserver is actually serving two completely different directories depending on protocol.  It's impossible to say beyond speculation without a first hand look at your server config and theme code.